# cannot use class QProcess in qt on windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, cmd, uac, qprocess

I just used QProcess to execute a exe file in qt on windows XP. It works normally, while not on windows 7. I think it's obviously because of the UAC issue on windows 7(or windows VISTA). Does anyone can help me to solve this problem please? Thanks in advance. And here's my code:

```
QProcess p(0);
p.start("cmd", QStringList()<<"/c"<<"copy .\\tmp\\GamesKoreClient.exe .\\GamesKoreClient.exe");
```

Comment: do you have a line `p.waitForFinished();` somewhere after p.start?

Comment: Did you check `p.error()`, `p.exitCode()` or anything that can lead you to solution before writing here?

Comment: @Shf thank you, it's really the p.waitForFinished() issue, and it works after adding it.

Comment: @KamilKlimek it works after adding p.waitForFinished().

Comment: Ok, i'll post it as answer then

Answer (score 0):

You start process correctly, but to receive results, you have to wait until this process is finished. Add this line after you started process:

```
p.waitForFinished();
```

And close precess afterwards:

```
p.close()
```